# How to make Yii sendFile function to set Content-Desposition to inline?

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to use `Yii::app()->request->sendFile()` to display images in the view without the 'Download Dialog box' popping up, but I am unable to do so as sendFile is setting `Content-Desposition` to `attachment`. How do I make it set it to `inline` ?

BTW I have used xsendfile function, but ditched it as you need mod-xsendfile in Apache to use it.

Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display images in the view then you need to use `<img>` tags.

If you want the returned content to *be* an image (in which case it's meaningless to talk about a view) then all you need to do is usually no more than

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo $binaryImageContents;
Yii::app()->end();
```

That's also what `sendFile()` does in principle, although it offers a bit more convenience because it detects the appropriate MIME type from the file's extension and sends a bunch of additional HTTP response headers (including the undesirable `Content-Disposition` one). You can [take a look for yourself](http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/tags/1.1.10/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php#752).

Comment: What's undesirable about Content-Disposition?

Comment: @BradKent: Nothing about the header itself. =) It's "undesirable" given the question text.