# Why imagecreatefromjpeg does not work in yii framework?

Tags: yii

I'm trying to resize an image at runtime in yii, but does not work.

I tried this code in the view but it does not work.

*My code in view.php*

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('image.jpg');
echo imagejpeg($image);
```

My code in controller

```
    public function actionImage()
    {
            $this->render('image');
    }
```

Output html

```
<html debug="true">
<body style="margin: 0px; ">
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none; " src="http://localhost/yiiadministration/index.php?r=administration/products/image"/>
</body>
<script src="chrome-extension://bmagokdooijbeehmkpknfglimnifench/googleChrome.js"/>
</html>
```

P.S; the code in the view is just to see the operation, and not to scale the image, because I normally do this in php.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is the GD module installed?  What's the apache log show?

Comment: What does `var_dump($image)` output after you have called `$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('image.jpg');`. Is `$image` a valid resource?

Btw: `echo imagejpeg($image);` does not make sense, as `imagejpeg($image);` returns a boolean value that cannot be echo'd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A header has already been sent before the view is rendered so your code tries to send a new header and fails as it has already been sent.

You can either send that header from the controller or use an img tag in the view as said previously on stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117403/how-to-make-yii-sendfile-function-to-set-content-desposition-to-inline)

Also imagejpeg() outputs the image directly to the browser so the echo is wrong in that context.